# Will saving innerhtml allow to save all elements on page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to save a web page the content of which changes dynamically. For example, a user can add custom functions and they are added to the custom functions drop down list. I would like to save the "newly" updated page using PHP and AJAX. I tried getting the innerHTML of all the elements by wrapping them in a "main-body" div. When I display the result with the alert box, all the data seems to be captured. But when I post the data to my savedata.php file using the POST AJAX method the data is not saved. Only the first few lines of the data is saved.

The new options in the select boxes and the content of the textarea are not saved either. However, if I individually try to save the textarea and select box data using .value instead of innerHTML that works.

My question in a nutshell, is why doesn't the innerHTML data get saved despite the fact that the alert box shows all the data when I use documentGetById("main-body").innerHTML to get all the contents of my page. Here is some code

Javascript and AJAX Code

```javascript
function savehtml()
{
  //Make ajax call after setting up variables
  var saveme=document.getElementById('txtArea').innerHTML
  var filename = document.getElementById('nameoff').value
  var parameters="saveme="+saveme+"&filename="+filename
  ajaxr('savedata.php', "result", parameters)
}

function ajaxRequest() {
  var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] 
  if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
    for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++) {
      try {
        return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
      }
      catch(e) {
        //suppress error
      }
    }
  }
  else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
    return new XMLHttpRequest()
  else
    return false
}

function ajaxr(phpfilename, idofinnerhtml, parameters)
{
  var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest()
  mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (mygetrequest.readyState==4) {
      if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1) {
        alert(parameters)
        document.getElementById(idofinnerhtml).innerHTML="Result: "+mygetrequest.responseText
        /*document.getElementById("catbody").value="Result : "+mygetrequest.responseText*/
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById(idofinnerhtml).innerHTML="Result: Failed "
      }
    }
  }

  mygetrequest.open("POST", phpfilename, true)
  mygetrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  mygetrequest.send(parameters)
}
```

HTML Code

```
<body>

<div id="main-body">

<table>
 <tr>
 <td>

<textarea id="txtArea" name="txtArea" rows="10" cols="100"><?

  ?></textarea><br><br>
 </td>
```

```
     <h2>Quick tools</h2>
     <button onclick="addsigns();">Add a sign</button><br>
       <input type="radio" id="andsign" name="whichsign" value="&&">&&
     <input type="radio" id="orsign" name="whichsign" value="||">||
   <input type="radio" id="notsign" name="whichsign" value="!">!
....
<td>
<h2>Save file</h2>
<input id="nameoff" type="text">
<button onclick="savehtml();">Save html</button><br>
</td>
```

Php Code

```
$data=$_POST['saveme'];
$filename=$_POST['filename'];

echo $data;

$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');

flock($handle, LOCK_EX); 

fwrite($handle, $data);

flock($handle, LOCK_EX); 

fclose($handle);
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

Guess I seem to have figured out the problem. The problem resulted from using two browsers at the same time. Apparently Internet Explorer 8 shows the value of the textarea even in the innerHTML but Firefox doesn't. So when you save the data using Internet Explorer you have the value stored when you invoke innerHTML. As for firefox you need to use .value to get the value of textarea as the innerHTML will not contain it. Since I was testing in both browsers I must have looked at the alert innerHTML code of one thinking it would be the same in the other and then overwritten my file with the code of the other browser. Anyways, thanks for the help of those who contributed. Hopes it helps those who are in a similar problem as me.

Comment: try to `alert` before `mygetrequest.send(parameters)`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and what it shows is not what gets stored in the file. Weird isn't it?

Comment: Could it be that the server doesn't allow receiving the amount of data you try to send it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '+' on this line (not reading anything):

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
```

The file/folder you're writing to needs to have write permissions the server can access.